# thread 1:signal sigabrt error constraints withVisualFormat

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

i am designing my video app , and i dont use main.storyboard for design and only use codes in viewcontroller.swift  in xcode 8 swift 3
my problem is after i add  lines below to viewcontroller.swift :

```
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H: |-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": thumbnailImageView]))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V: |-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": thumbnailImageView]))
```

i did not have any error but after i run project its crashed and give me this error on appdelegate.swift :
[appdelegate.swift error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb2lF.png)

please help me about this

here is my [project source code download link](https://doc-10-8c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/5t3j8h77m3tokhfjvd4ihrp176pqa7j6/l3dj58eg2ab67fvrtl990j57p75ac2ar/1501336800000/12365261552502333511/12365261552502333511/0BwBdkOq59P7AQkJIN29iTFVCb0U?e=download&nonce=ac42e1dooipn4&user=12365261552502333511&hash=0tg9nlskolu7aq2dn9ff7khuma1j4ful).

Comment: check if your thumbnailImageView is added as subview before adding the constraint is a common error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that you are adding thumbnailImageView as subview for you current view and then I think problem is that there is space between "V: |" change it to V:| , do same for H: | . Your constraints should be like this

```
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": thumbnailImageView]))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-16-[v0]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": thumbnailImageView]))
```